# how to style the entire line instead of all cells

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qtstylesheets

I need to round the line of a QTableWidget so that it looks like this,

[image]

but when trying to set the border-radius it modifies all the cells
like this.
[image]

I found almost nothing about styling the table that was not written in C++
or that explained the stylization of rows in a table

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(400, 303)
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(Form)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(Form)
        self.tableWidget.setStyleSheet("QTableWidget{\n"
        "background-color: white;\n"
        "color:black;\n"
        "border-bottom: 2px solid white;\n"
        "border-right: 2px solid white;\n"
        "}\n"
        "\n"
        "QTableView::item {\n"
        "border-bottom: 1px solid #d6d9dc;\n"
        "border-top: 1px solid #d6d9dc;\n"
        "margin-bottom:5px;\n"
        "border-radius:10px;\n"
        "\n"
        "\n"
        "\n"
        "\n"
        "}\n"
        "QTableView::section{\n"
        "color:blue;\n"
        "}")
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(3)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(2)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, item)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setVisible(False)
        self.tableWidget.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.tableWidget)
        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)
    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "New Row"))
        item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "New Row"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "New Column"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "New Column"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(2)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "New Column"))
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

What is wrong whith the code above?

Comment: Please don't post code (including stylesheet) as images, as it makes trying to reproduce your issue very annoying, as we need to copy everything by hand (and we could make some mistakes or miss some of yours). That said, that stylesheet is set for the table or for any parent? Are you sure you didn't set another (possibly generic) stylesheet on any of the parent widgets, including the window? I'd suggest you to include the complete code of the ui file.

Comment: please provide a [mRE]

Comment: The M.R.E  is already on the question, sorry for not posting it before

Comment: @PeterTorbenn sorry, I misread your question, as I thought that the issue was about the rounded border of the table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this is possible by setting the style sheet of the table widget, but it could be done by setting the item delegate of your table to a custom `QStyledItemDelegate` where you override `paint` and `sizeHint`, e.g.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class MyStyledItem(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, margin, radius, border_color, border_width, parent=None):
        """ 
        margin: distance between border and top of cell
        radius: radius of rounded corner
        border_color: color of border
        border_width: width of border
        """       
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.margin = margin
        self.radius = radius
        self.border_color = border_color
        self.border_width = border_width

    def sizeHint(self, option, index):
        # increase original sizeHint to accommodate space needed for border
        size = super().sizeHint(option, index)
        size = size.grownBy(QtCore.QMargins(0, self.margin, 0, self.margin))
        return size

    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        painter.save()
        painter.setRenderHint(painter.Antialiasing)

        # set clipping rect of painter to avoid painting outside the borders
        painter.setClipping(True)
        painter.setClipRect(option.rect)
        
        # call original paint method where option.rect is adjusted to account for border
        option.rect.adjust(0, self.margin, 0, -self.margin)
        super().paint(painter, option, index)

        pen = painter.pen()
        pen.setColor(self.border_color)
        pen.setWidth(self.border_width)
        painter.setPen(pen)
        # draw either rounded rect for items in first or last column or ordinary rect
        if index.column() == 0:
            rect = option.rect.adjusted(self.border_width, 0, self.radius + self.border_width, 0)
            painter.drawRoundedRect(rect, self.radius, self.radius)
        elif index.column() == index.model().columnCount(index.parent()) - 1:
            rect = option.rect.adjusted(-self.radius-self.border_width, 0, -self.border_width, 0)
            painter.drawRoundedRect(rect, self.radius, self.radius)
        else:
            rect = option.rect.adjusted(-self.border_width, 0, self.border_width, 0)
            painter.drawRect(rect)
        # draw lines between columns
        if index.column() > 0:
            painter.drawLine(option.rect.topLeft(), option.rect.bottomLeft())
        painter.restore()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    # create test table
    table = QtWidgets.QTableWidget()
    table.setRowCount(3)
    table.setColumnCount(3)
    for row in range(table.rowCount()):
        for col in range(table.columnCount()):
            table.setItem(row, col, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(f'item at {row=}, {col=}'))

    table.setShowGrid(False)
    delegate = MyStyledItem(margin=3, radius=10, border_width=2, border_color=QtGui.QColor("navy"))
    table.setItemDelegate(delegate)
    # the custom styled item delegate can be used with a style sheet
    table.setStyleSheet("QTableView::item {border: 0px; padding: 10px; }")
    # next line is needed to call the sizeHint of the item delegate
    table.resizeRowsToContents()
    table.show()
    app.exec()
```

**Screenshot:**

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i never face delegate in pyqt5 its a great learning.